# Access button properties of a button which is inside a GameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to access button properties such as `.interactable = false;` of a button which is inside a GameObject. I want to access the button via GameObject. I tried below method but i could only access few properties like `.SetActive`.

`gameObjectA.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(false);`

where gameObjectA is my GameObject and GetChild(0) is my Button

I want to access other properties such as `.Color`, `.Interactable` etc.

Please Help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you trying to get the button controller attached to the child object?

Comment: No. My child object is the Button. What i want is basically follow below steps when getting properties of a button: Access GameObject -> then access the button which is the child of GameObject -> and finally the properties of that button. I hope this clarifies. I am new to Unity so sorry if this sounds confusing.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html .. please make sure to learn the basics before starting to implement your own app :) .. see e.g. https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/getcomponent

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`GetComponentInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html), this will return the first instance of a button found in the gameobject or one of its children (recursive)

```cs
Button childbutton = GetComponentInChildren<Button>();
childbutton.interactable = false;
```

If you have several children with buttons you can the `gameObject.transform.GetChild()` that you were already using with a normal [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html)(replace x with the child index)

```cs
Button childbutton = gameObjectA.transform.GetChild(x).GetComponent<Button>();
```

You can also assign and read [tags](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-do-i-get-child-game-object-with-a-certain-tag.343475/) or [names](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html) if you are changing and adding buttons constanly and dont want to rechange your code